# jQuery execution order

Tags: jquery

I am wondering why in my example #1 the alerts fire in the proper order 1, 2 but in example #2 where I add an ajax call does the firing order then become 2,1. Also could anyone suggest how with using an ajax call could I achieve the desired firing order of 1, 2... I am stumped.

Example #1

```
uploader.bind('BeforeUpload', function (up, file, policy, sinature) {
    //alert('1');

    test();
    function test() {
        alert('1');
    }
});

uploader.bind('UploadFile', function (up, file, policy, signature) {
    test2();
    function test2() {
        alert('2');
    }
});
```

Example #2

```
uploader.bind('BeforeUpload', function (up, file, policy, sinature) {
    //alert('1');

    test();
    function test() {
        data = { alc: 'private', bucket: 'PhotojimaDev', file: file.name, key: path };
        $.ajax({
            url: sf.getServiceRoot('photojima') + "Upload/getPolicy",
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            beforeSend: sf.setModuleHeaders
        }).done(function (response, status) {
            if (status == "success") {
                policy = response.policy;
                signature = response.signature;
                alert('1');
            }
        }).fail(function (xhr, result, status) {
            alert("Uh-oh, something broke: " + status);
        });
    }
});

uploader.bind('UploadFile', function (up, file, policy, signature) {
    test2();
    function test2() {
        alert('2');
    }
});
```

Comment: AJAX is by definition Asynchronous. Which means it will not wait for the server to respond before continuing with alert 2. You can solve this by making it synchronous (not recommended), adding a delay for alert 2, or adding another AJAX call for alert 2 as well. In most cases the order will not be predictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax in `BeforeUpload` creates a non-blocking background worker that obviously doesn't finish until after `UploadFile`

If you need `BeforeUpload` to finish first, then you will have to tell `$.ajax` to not run asynchronously by adding `async = false`

```
function test() {
    data = { alc: 'private', bucket: 'PhotojimaDev', file: file.name, key: path };
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: sf.getServiceRoot('photojima') + "Upload/getPolicy",
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: sf.setModuleHeaders
    }).done(function (response, status) {
        if (status == "success") {
            policy = response.policy;
            signature = response.signature;
            alert('1');
        }
    }).fail(function (xhr, result, status) {
        alert("Uh-oh, something broke: " + status);
    });
}
```

Search for async in manual: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

`ajax` is by default asyn so a ajax request is send and then the code after that is executed
so in the second case you get 2 , 1 
because 1 will be fired only when the ajax request a `success response`

to get the desired 1,2 execution you can call the function test2() from within the success handler
OR 
just make the ajax request sync. this can be done setting `async to false` when sending the ajax request. but is not recomended

Comment: Exactly.  The ajax in the first request creates a non-blocking background worker that obviously doesnt finish until after alert(2)

Comment: @ParvSharma Thanks for the insight. Now my conundrum becomes that the code executed in uploader.bind('UploadFile'... needs to be executed after the success of the ajax call from uploader.bind('BeforeUpload'... I can not move the code from  uploader.bind('UploadFile'... to the ajax success callback.. How might I control this workflow?

Comment: this is an uploader plugin called plupload http://www.plupload.com/example_custom.php

Comment: and whats stopping you from just transferring you function test2() to the success of the ajax request?